# What effects will reduce the scuttle's defenses?

Tags: league-of-legends

I know that things like stun will cause the scuttle to take -50 armor and magic resist which makes a huge difference.

But what types of skills will do this, particularly border cases. Like stuns do, but what about roots, silences, slows etc. Or repositions like vayne's condemn, janna's ult or even ryze's ult? Cass's grounding? etc.

Answer (score 4):

Hard CC will activate the Scuttle Crab's resistance reductions. Hard CC is everything that is

- A Stun (Leona's Q)
- Suspension, aka Knockup (Janna's Q)
- A Displacive Knockup (Lee Sin's R)
- Charmed (Ahri's E)
- Feared (Fiddlesticks' Q)
- Taunted (Rammus' E)

---

Resistance reductions will also work, such as Wukong's Q, or Black Cleaver.

Comment: Do purely displacement abilities also count? Something like a Singed fling, or a Nautalius or Blitzcrank hook for example.

Comment: There are no pure displacement abilities. Blitzcrank stuns targets, Singed puts the target in suspension (therefore akin to a knockup). Nautilus also stuns.
I'm not sure about Janna's R though

Answer (score 2):

According the the wiki page for the [Rift Scuttler](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Rift_Scuttler):

> Rift Scuttler has several unique interactions with crowd control:
>
> - Crowd control effects against her last twice as long.
> - **When affected by crowd control that prevents her movement**, Rift Scuttler permanently loses 50 armor and magic resist. This can only occur one time after each spawn.
> - While Rift Scuttler is under the effect of crowd control that prevents her movement, she receives 25% extra damage from all sources, including true damage.

Emphasis my own

Further testing in a custom game I've noticed that the -50 armor and magic resist persists after the CC ends (seen by clicking on the crab and checking its resists before, during and after the effect), but the 25% extra damage does not. It can however be reapplied multiple times after ending without killing the crab.

I tested this with Lux since she has a root and a slow. Slows also do not apply those debuffs, but roots will as they stop the crab from moving. I did this test at level 3

1. Auto Attacks before casting any spells dealt **42** damage.
2. Auto Attacks while under the effects of the root dealt **76** damage
3. Auto Attacks after the root wore off dealt **60** damage